# How to generate XML with open and close tag for NULL/empty value columns in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, json, xml

I am working with SQL XML. I want to generate XML with open and close tag for NULL/empty value columns in sql. Please find below tables and query:

Tables:

emp:

```
+-------+---------+
| empid | empname |
+-------+---------+
|     1 | Arul    |
|     2 | Ram     |
|     3 | Nivi    |
+-------+---------+
```

empdetail:

```
+-------+------------+----------------+
| empid | empaddress |    empemail    |
+-------+------------+----------------+
|     1 | Chennai    | mail1@mail.com |
|     2 | Madurai    | mail2@mail.com |
|     3 | Mumbai     | NULL           |
+-------+------------+----------------+
```

Sql query:

```
select A.empid,A.empname,
(select B.empaddress,isnull(B.empemail,'') as empemail from empdetail B where A.empid=B.empid  for xml path('EmployeeDetails'),type) 
from emp A 
where A.empid=1 for xml path('root')
```

This query gives expected data like below:

```
<root>
  <empid>1</empid>
  <empname>Arul</empname>
  <EmployeeDetails>
    <empaddress>Chennai</empaddress>
    <empemail>mail1@mail.com</empemail>
  </EmployeeDetails>
</root>
```

but this query gives this tag **`<empemail />`**  When i move to empid 3:

```
<root>
  <empid>3</empid>
  <empname>Nivi</empname>
  <EmployeeDetails>
    <empaddress>Mumbai</empaddress>
    <empemail />
  </EmployeeDetails>
</root>
```

But I want open and close tag even column value is NULL. like below:

```
<root>
  <empid>3</empid>
  <empname>Nivi</empname>
  <EmployeeDetails>
    <empaddress>Mumbai</empaddress>
    <empemail></empemail>
  </EmployeeDetails>
</root>
```

Comment: According to the Xml specification the tagname in the closing angle bracket is optional.  So there shouldn't be any reason the change your code.  The Net Library doesn't give the results you are asking.  I would leave everything the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<empemail />` is the standard way to represent an empty field.

You can replace the value with a space or some other value:

```
select e.empid, e.empname,
       (select ed.empaddress, coalesce(ed.empemail, ' ') as empemail
         from empdetail ed
         where e.empid = ed.empid
         for xml path('EmployeeDetails'), type
        ) 
from emp e
where e.empid = 3
for xml path('root')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2da6d3630ff8ce17f7756ebf9dccfb79) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Bro, its working. So, I need to give single space instead of empty space. Thanks, Bro.